# Change part of an excel forumla to include data from another cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am looking for an easy way to replace part of a formula in Excel.

I have to do this for over 66,000 formulas every year. Currently i use Find & Replace to speed up the job but it still takes me several hours to do it.

```
='C:\Excel\[File1.xlsm]08-01-20'!V5
```

I want to replace the `08-01-20` part of the above formula with the value of cell `C2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two lists in the format `"dd-mm-yy",` (one with the incorrect dates, one with the correct

Then replace the example dates in the below script & Run.

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

 fndList = Array("04-01-20", "11-01-20")
 rplcList = Array("05-01-20", "12-01-20")

  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Indirect

```
=INDIRECT("'C:\Excel\[File1.xlsm]" & TEXT(C2,"dd-mm-yy") & "'!V5")
```

Just be aware that too many of these volatile functions will slow down Excel as they will re-calc every time anything changes in Excel and that they require the referenced workbook to be open to calc.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I am getting a #REF error even though i have the other workbook open. =INDIRECT("'C:\Excel\[File1.xlsm]" & C2 & "'!V5")

Comment: What is the data type in C2?  Is it a date, or the actual string you need to insert?

Comment: "06/01/2020" formatted as "dd-mm-yy" because a date in C2 is the tab name of another workbook. I have a tab with a bunch of dates all corresponding to every Monday in the year, another tab containing every Tuesday etc, but every year the dates slip so my original formula i posted, its date does not actually correspond to a Monday in the year 2020. That is why i need to correct it.

Comment: use `TEXT()` like this  =INDIRECT("'C:\Excel[File1.xlsm]" & TEXT(C2,"DD-MM-YY") & "'!V5")

Comment: Still getting a #REF error. The workbook is a shared file (although currently im the only person with it open). Could the fact that its shared cause the formula to fail? i can click the next cell down and reference a cell from the File1.xlsx workbook with no issues. Its as if it doesn't understand INDIRECT or can't see the file open when using INDIRECT

Comment: Further INDIRECT.EXT won't work for me since I am running a 64bit version of Office 2013.